# Using aria-labelledby to refer to self and others IDs is not working

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I am new to web accessibility and learning it based on Youtube videos. I watched this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8xUCzToff8

and notice that using aria-labelledby to refer to self and others IDs is not working. From the following screenshot of this video

[image]

This code snippet (copied from the screenshot)

```
   <h2 id="lbl">Men's Outerwear</h2>
   <button id="btn" aria-labelledby="lbl btn">Shop Now</button>
```

should pronounce "men's outerwear, shop now, button" via screen reader. However, when I tested it with the Screen Reader extension in Chrome, I only heard "men's outerwear". What did I miss?

Actually, I need to use the same HTML structure as shown above in my real web application. So, I need to find out why the above code is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug in your screen reader plugin.  You're not testing with a [standard screen reader](https://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey9/#primary) that real users use.  Try one of these:

- [JAWS](https://support.freedomscientific.com/Downloads/JAWS) (PC) - it has a free trial mode so you can test your example.
- [NVDA](https://www.nvaccess.org/download/) (PC) - completely free although donations are accepted.
- [VoiceOver](https://www.apple.com/voiceover/info/guide/_1121.html) (Mac) - already installed on Macs
- [VoiceOver](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/turn-on-and-practice-voiceover-iph3e2e415f/ios) (iOS) - already installed on iOS devices

I use `aria-labelledby` **all the time** and it works great with multiple IDs on all the above screen readers.